# iOS 5: Text Color for UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd

Tags: objective-c

I'm able to change the text color of *UIBarButtonItem* using this code snippet (iOS 5+):

```
NSMutableDictionary *attributes = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[attributes setValue:[UIColor blackColor] forKey:UITextAttributeTextColor];   
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:attributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Unfortunately this does not affect *UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd*.

Is there a way to change the text color of the *UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd* ?

Comment: not really -- the system bar button items are composed of an image -- the "+" in the button is a PNG and not a string.

Comment: Okay, I see. Thanks for your answer. I think I will work around this by using a custom bar button item with the plus sign as a string. Maybe you want to add your comment as an answer to this question so I can mark the question as solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know no way to achieve this -- system UIBarButtonItem instances use images instead of text, so changing their color cannot be done by changing their title text color. You most likely have to create your own bar button item.

Answer (score 4):

Use setTintColor. For example:

```
[downloadButtonItem setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:247.0/255.0 green:247.0/255.0 blue:247.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
```